# How do you place a groupbox in a QMenuBar?

Tags: qt

[image]

I need the groupbox that contains the ID picture and a button on the right side of the QMenuBar, and I don't know how to do that. Here's what I have so far:

```
QGridLayout *menulayout = new QGridLayout();
QWidget *menuwidget = new QWidget (dynamic_cast<QMainWindow*>(this->parent())->menuBar());
menulayout->setContentsMargins(18,0,18,0);

menulayout->addWidget(menuwidget);
menulayout->addWidget(_ui->groupBox_UserMenu, 0 ,0);

dynamic_cast<QMainWindow*>(this->parent())->menuBar()->setLayout(menulayout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by placing the groupbox on the desired position on the Form and then set it's parent to the QMenu Bar. The first lines of code I posted were unnecessary.

```
_ui->groupBox_UserMenu->setParent(_ui->menuBar);
```